# Типы переменных в Ruby

Tags: ruby

Чем в Ruby отличаются переменная экземпляра класса и переменная объекта?

Comment: Терминология: объект == экземпляр класса.

Answer (score 3):

Во первых, объект - это экземпляр класса. Это одно и то же понятие. Еще можно часто встретить слово "инстанс", тоже означающее "экземпляр класса".

Во вторых, кроме инстанс-, и класс-переменных, есть ещё одна интересная вещь - класс-инстанс переменная (или инстанс-переменная уровня класса).

Они похожи на классовые переменные. Но если классовые переменные расшаривают *значение* и для классов, унаследованных от текущего, то класс-инстанс переменные - только для конкретного класса, и не наследуются.
(они являются предпочтительным решением, если нет нужды в расшаривании переменной с наследниками).

Фишка в том, что в руби, любой объявленный класс является экземпляром класса `Class`.
И у этих самых объектов класса `Class` тоже могут быть свои инстанс-методы (уровня класса).

Ну и к слову: любой объект в руби (в том числе класс), является экземпляром класса `Object`.
Отсюда выражение "класс - это объект, а объект - это класс".

Answer (score 2):

Каждый класс является инстансом типа *Class* и каждый класс является подклассом типа *Object* (в 1.8 - in 1.9 каждый класс является подклассом *BasicObject*'a).
Таким образом, каждый класс является объектом в том смысле, что он является экземпляром подкласса *Object*, т.е. класса. Другими словами, нету отличий между перменной класса и объекта.

Answer (score 0):

*Значение* переменной экземпляра доступно только *внутри экземпляра*, к которому она принадлежит.

Answer (score 0):

ничем не отличается, так как объект это экземпляр класса

Answer (score 0):

Свои 5 копеек.. )
Насколько я понял речь идет о  экземпляре класса и  объекте класса.

Объект класса(читай класс) - это своего рода "каркас" по которому строятся 
экземпляры класса..

К примеру переменные объекта класса являются общими для всех экземпляров класса..

class SomeClass   #SomeClass - это объект класса(собственно каркас)
 
  @@class_var = -10 # это переменная объекта класса(или просто класса) она   имеет
 #одно значение для всех экземпляров класса и все могут изменить ее

  def initialize(x,y)
    @x,@y = x,y #это переменные экземпляра класса они у каждого экземпляра свои 

# и имееют свои значения для каждого экземпляра
  end

end

some_obj = SomeClass.new(-1,-1) #some_obj это экземпляр класса его @x, @y = -1,-1
 а его @@class_var = -10
some_obj_next = SomeClass.new(-2,-2) #some_obj_next это экземпляр класса его @x, @y = 
-2,-2
 а его @@class_var = -10(ибо это общая переменная объекта класcа для всех )